# How do you find an element in a Vector of tuples by comparing with a specific index in the tuple?

Tags: rust

I have the following hash maps defined:

```rust
let mut adj_list: HashMap<String, Vec<String>>;
let mut adj_matrix: HashMap<String, Vec<(String, bool)>> = HashMap::new();
```

I also have the loop:

```rust
for (src, _neighbors) in self.adj_list.iter() {
    for (dest, _n) in self.adj_list.iter(){
        let d: &mut (String, bool) = adj_matrix.get_mut(src)
            .into_iter()
            .find(|&x| x == dest) // Error here
            .unwrap();
        // Do something with the tuple d
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
adj_matrix.get_mut(src).into_iter().find(|&x| x == dest);
                                                ^^ no implementation for `Vec<(String, bool)> == String`
```

which makes sense to me, directly comparing a string to a tuple should make no sense. However I'm having trouble figuring out how to compare the dest string with the first element of the tuple.

I have tried:

```rust
adj_matrix.get_mut(src).into_iter().find(|&x| x.1 == dest);
```

but that gives me the error:

```
adj_matrix.get_mut(src).into_iter().find(|&x| x.1 == dest);
                                                ^ unknown field
```

What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: While the first answer given so far is onto something, it would be much easier for us to help, if you arranged your code snippets such, that we can simply paste it into https://play.rust-lang.org/ I wager, if you had tried to do so, you would have already found the problem yourself.

Comment: You are right, I didn't think to post the code snippet on an online compiler. It would have been much easier to debug if I did. I will keep that in mind for next time!

Comment: Nit: you can iterate over the keys only in hashmap with `.keys()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `adj_matrix` variable is a HashMap of vectors.

The error you get gives you a hint:

> ^^ no implementation for `Vec<(String, bool)> == String`

You're not comparing a tuple to a string, you are comparing a Vec of tuples to a String, which does not make sense either.

### Why do you have a Vec here while it looks like you should have a tuple?

Let's look at the types here:

```
let d: &mut (String, bool) = adj_matrix.get_mut(src) // --> Option<&mut Vec<(String, bool)>>
        .into_iter() // --> impl Iterator<Item = &mut Vec<(String, bool)>>
        .find(|&x| x == dest) // x -> Vec<(String, bool)>
        .unwrap();
```

This is caused by the fact that `Option` does implement `IntoIter`, and returns an iterator that returns 0 or 1 element, depending on whether it's a Some() or a None.

To fix your issue, you first need to make sure you actually have an entry for the `src` key.

It could look like something like this:

```
for (src, _neighbors) in self.adj_list.iter() {
    for (dest, _n) in self.adj_list.iter(){
        if let Some(v) = adj_matrix.get_mut(src) {
            let d: &mut (String, bool) = v
                .into_iter()
                .find(|&x| x == dest)
                .unwrap();
            // Do something with the tuple d
        } else {
            // src was not found
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, if let Some(v) was the key that I was missing here.